# How to make computer use internet only with proxy SQUID PFSENSE

Tags: squid, pfsense

My computer still access the internet although squid is inatalled.
IF i manually put proxy setting then internet also works.

How can stop internet if proxy is not entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your router/firewall, disable egress on 80/tcp and 443/tcp from all IPs except for that of your proxy server.

Comment: you mean source port should be 80 or destination port should be 80

Comment: Rule should be applied on LAN or WAN

Comment: The destination port should be 80 (and/or 443).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a silly question, but why not turn on the transparent proxy option?

I assume that the PFSense box is your gateway and if the transparent proxy option is turned on all of your HTTP traffic will go through the proxy.  This way you won't need to manually enter proxy information for each machine on the network.

Comment: i will try that